# How to get Datetimepicker with seconds in asp.net?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i have a task that i have to filter the records based on DateFrom and DateTo.
in mysql the date fromat is in '2014-07-18 20:03:08' like this.
In front end i used DatetimePicker to textbox..datetimepicker format results gives 
'2014/07/09 14:00'.
so not possible for compare db dateformat and datetime formate.

i want datetime picker with seconds..plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DateTimePicker` stores a `DateTime` in the `Value` property. You can add desired seconds to it:

```
DateFrom.Value = DateFrom.Value.AddSeconds(seconds);
```

> datetimepicker format results gives '2014/07/09 14:00'.

Don't use strings as parameters for datetime-columns in MySql. Instead use sql-parameters and pass the `DateTime` directly:

```
// add seconds if you want, but i don't see any reason for it
// maybe you want to include the To-date, then you can add a day - one second
DateTo.Value = DateTo.Value.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("connStr"))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        string sql = @"SELECT t.From, t.To, OtherColumns...
                       FROM TableName t 
                       WHERE FROM >= @From AND To <= @To";
        using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", DateFrom.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", DateTo.Value);
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                { 
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime pickers aren't always made for this accuracy.

I suggest using a customized DateTime picker with textboxes to allow your users to input complete time in seconds.